# Gmail share link with image in body

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gmail

I want to share a link using the gmail and i need a image related to the link to be showed in the body of the message. Im trying to place the image using "< img src>" in the gmail's  body parameter, but the img src code is being showing in the body as a text.

My code:

```
String body = "<img src=\"http://mywebsite.com/App_themes/Gale/Not/" + sSelecao + ".jpg"
+ "\" alt=\"Notícia\"> Acesse o link para ler a notícia: http://www.mywebsite.com?info=" + sSelecao;

String sCompartilhamento = "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?view=cm&fs=1&to&su=Notícias - " 
+ Session["CompartilhamentoTitulo"].ToString() + "&body="+body+"&ui=2&tf=1";
```

Result:

Title: Notícias - Algum Texto Qualquer

Body:

```
<img src="http://mywebsite.com/App_themes/Gale/Not/632.jpg" alt="Notícia">Acesse o link para ler a notícia: http://mywebsite.com?info=632
```

**What can i do to the image be showed in the body instead of the "img src" code using a gmail share link?**

Comment: Usually, you have to create a html file with your images inside, add it in your web application, and specify it as your message's body. or you can put your images in joined files.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Thanks for you comment, but I need to do it using the gmail share link

Comment: @AntoinePelletier but anything in the "$body=" parameter appears as a simple text.

Comment: before sending : Message.IsHtml = true;

Comment: @AntoinePelletier i understand what you are saying, this may work in other cases when you send the email by code, but im not using the MailMessage class, im using the gmail's share link to "share" a link from my website, in other words im preparing a email to be sent by the user (sending to gmail the title and body).

Comment: That's why the image is problematique. Does the message window open ? it's ready to be sent by the user, but you want the message to already contain an images when the window open ?

Comment: You want to open a GMail message editor and place your image inside the client's editor imediatly when it opens, with a single line of code... i'm not an expert but ... I think you'll need to study google's mail API